# Matplotlib label overlap because there are too many data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

This is my code in jupyter notebook in python language.
**I have distance in vertical, and time in horizontal.**
When the data is flooding (too many), the **horizontal labels overlap each other**. You can't read the label at all. How can I have something like dynamic width of the frame? Or maybe other solution is very welcome. Thank you

```
    #this code below is to append the data
    if i==0:
        time = [timetable[i][0]]
    else:
        time.append(timetable[i][0])
    if timetable[i][1][:-2].lower() == 'driver':
        distances.append(0)
    elif timetable[i][1][:-2].lower() == 'rider':
        distances.append(rider_request)
    print(time, len(time))
    print(distances, len(distances))

    #dataframe for plot graph
    df=pd.DataFrame({'x': time, 'y': distances })

    # plot
    plt.plot( 'x', 'y', data=df, linestyle='-', marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

[image: Graph Plot]

Comment: can you try print(df.dtypes)?

Comment: @warped dtype: object